# How to prevent ReactJS app from refreshing after every navigation using react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

The application has announcement feature which basically shows images that are being uploaded by other user. In first load, the images loaded well, but when user navigates through the the application (using react-router and switch) announcement feature will only show 1 image when our firebase DB has currently more than 1 image being stored

```
    class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <div className="App">
                    <div>

                        <div className="content">
                            <Switch>
                                <Route exact path="/" component={Dash} />
                                <Route path="/sumbong" component={Sumbong} />
                                <Route path="/docproc" component={DocProcessing}/>
                                <Route path="/announce" component={Announce}/>
                            </Switch>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div className="navi">
                        <SideNavigation  />
                    </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Make sure you use `<Link>` component or `this.props.history.push` to navigate to other URLs, a normal `<a href='/announce'>` would cause app refresh.

Comment: I did use <Link> to navigate to other pages, but still it reloads everything